# key press feedback popup showing blank window on key press in a soft keyboard

Tags: android-layout, android-softkeyboard

i implemented a custom soft keyboard using the code snippet in the SoftKeyboard sample in android-sdk.  However, when the apk is run on the emulator, after the custom soft keyboard pops up, when a key is pressed, the key press preview popup window just shows a small blank square window, and does not show the character of the key pressed inside the preview window.

Can someone help ?

thanks

Comment: Were you able to figure out this issue?

Comment: @Anonsage,   Yes, got a solution, although the solution came as a response to another question posted separately.  Here is the link to that question and answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031438/setting-keypreviewlayout-for-android-virtual-keyboard-is-causing-a-crash/16793140#16793140) . In short, you need to add a keypreviewlayout.xml and reference it in the softkeyboard layout as shown in the question and answer in the link above

Comment: @VikrantY,  i didn't have a chance to try out your solution, since i got a different solution long before i saw this solution.

Comment: @Anonsage,  you might want to try out the solution posted by VikrantY before trying out the solution i pointed out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try out that other link too. I already tried VikrantY's answer, but that didn't work and is for long-clicks rather than regular clicks.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add

```
 android:popupCharacters="w"
```

to your key entries

Sample entry is as below:

```
<Key android:codes="87" android:keyLabel = "W" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup" android:popupCharacters="w"  />
```

Comment: This unfortunately just allows the key's long-click prompt to show. The blank window that appears when the key is touched is still blank.